# i need some help (registry system) - php+mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

My problem is not with how to write the code, but in the database strategy and the best way to write to the database.

My HTML has 2 divs, and each div represents a section.  In the first section, the user enters their name, email, and password.  In the second section, the user enters their address, country, and job.

Is best to save the values to the database as each section is completed?  Or is it better to submit all values from both sections at one time?  I prefer to insert into the db each section independently.

Another question, it is best to have a unique table for all data where fields from both sections are saved in a single record, or should I create two separate tables?  If I create two separate tables, how do I connect them?  (ok...foreign key, but i don't have much experience in DB)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would store each slides values into the `$_SESSION` var. When finished with registration, send the `$_SESSION` values to the DB.

**somewhere on top of your scripts**

```
session_start();
```

**slide 1**
When finished, do this:

```
$userinfo = array();
$userinfo['name'] = $name_from_formular;
$userinfo['mail'] = $mail_from_formular;
$_SESSION['userinfo'] = $userinfo;
```

**slide 2**

```
if(isset($_SESSION['userinfo'])) {

    $userinfo = $_SESSION['userinfo'];

}

$userinfo['country'] = $country_from_formular;
// ....
$_SESSION['userinfo'] = $userinfo;
```

**submit data**

(read from `$_SESSION` and send it to the DB)

Comment: ok, i understand the logic, thanks! when you insert the content in the db, you make something like - insert into users (name, email)values ($userinfo['name'], $userinfo['email'], the normal way, or you use $_SESSION['userinfo'] ?

Comment: I would retreive `$userinfo` from `$_SESSION` but you can also insert `$_SESSION['userinfo']['name']` if you want to.